# sending a lot of email in newsletter module

Tags: php, email, newsletter

i am writing a newsletter module in php/mysql.

how can i send email to site subscriptors that doesn't cause my mail server get blocked ? i mean it doesn't treat as a spam sender?

Comment: Why not setting up an rss feed instead of a newsletter?

Comment: [sendgrid.com](http://www.sendgrid.com) would be the easiest way.

Comment: Or just integrate with something like MailChimp or CampaignMonitor - their servers are already whitelisted.

Comment: @eckes: it is not decision. my boss asked me to do it with newsletter to send different item updates,like news,articles,page ....

Comment: Then your boss is making a bad decision. Sending email with a high delivery rate is HARD, and if you don't even know where to start, your chances of doing it successfully in short period of time is a number approaching 0.

Answer (score 5):

The *full* answer to this question is really outside of the scope of this site, as much of it will involve administrative tasks with the domain and server(s) involved.

But the short answer is: Don't do this! You *will* just end up getting your server's IP blacklisted, making even low-volume e-mail sending worthless from that server.

You should look at other options; an RSS feed, a third-party, well-run mailing service (like Constant Contact), or something else.

Comment: Your question was asking how to avoid it. My answer is, "You don't know enough to even have a chance to avoid it". Getting blacklisted is essentially irreversible. It's not worth the risk.

Answer (score 1):

Use Cron job to do this and send mails in small chunks with a time difference.

Comment: cron job option is available in cpanel.

Answer (score 1):

There are several rules that you need to follow if you want to send out emails from your site and have then not being flagged as spam:

1. Start with the most obvious: check to make sure IP address of your server is not on any spam black lists. Try this site: [link text](http://www.dnsbl.info/)
2. By default all emails sent from a website hosted on Apache server are send from the user Apache server runs under, usually 'nobody'. This is a red flag for spam filters, so you have to modify the value of 'return-path' header which is not always allowed by email server. If you can't modify return-path, then you need to start apache as another user, create a new account for your apache server, name it anything you like as long as it's not 'nobody' and then configure apache server to run as this new user
3. Very important to have reverse DNS entry for the IP address you use for sending out emails. That reverse DNS entry must point to same domain name that points to this IP address. This is actually the most important thing to do. Since only a webhost can add reverse DNS entry, you should ask your host to do this for you.

Other smaller steps that can help is to configure an appropriate spf entry in your DNS server and another one is to use digital signature to sign all your outgoing messages. I used to use a program called dksign for this, it's probably not the most up-to date program now, so do your research and find the best way to sign your messages.

Use common sense when creating subject lines. If you say "free discount offer" in the subject line or something similar or "get viagra", your message will probably be flagged as spam no matter what.